# How to Increase Wordpress JSON API Speed?

Tags: api, json

My Developer used JSON API Wordpress plugin for build Android app for my website. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)
But App loading speed is too slow, like it takes 10 seconds to load info of 5 posts (Screenshot Attached).
Any way to increase it's speed?[image: screenshot]

Comment: I personally haven't done it, but you can try using a caching plugin. My circle of friends prefer Varnish however a quick Google search led me to this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-cache/

Comment: Yeah.. Already tried this plugin. It didn't helped!!

Comment: Also using varnish with my website, still it's too slow

Comment: That sucks man. Hopefully someone can point you in the right direction.... Does your server perform well though?

Comment: yes no issues in main website. it's blazing fast

Comment: @MissingTricks Were you able to get any help on this issue? If so, I would love to hear what you found.

Comment: same problem in woocommerce rest api it take 8 seconds (!) to load 32 products in android app